# regarding if conditionals in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
console.log("Batman glares at you.");
var userAnswer = prompt("Are you feeling lucky, punk?");
if (userAnswer==="yes")
{
console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}
else
{
console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
}
```

Here i want to run command such that if userAnswer takes more than one value other than yes for the 1st console.log statement
i.e
i want to assign "ya" as also the userAnswer of 1st console.log statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add more options in your if:

```
if (userAnswer==="yes" || userAnswer==="yea" || userAnswer==="yup"){
    console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}
```

`||` means "OR". So, if the answer is `"yes"`, OR the answer is `"yea"`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log("Batman glares at you.");
var userAnswer = prompt("Are you feeling lucky, punk?");
if (["yes","ya","yo","yeaaaa","list goes on here"].indexOf(userAnswer)!=-1)
{
console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}
else
{
console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
userAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase(); //Convert string to lower case. "Yes" ==> "yes"
userResponsesArray = ["yes","ya","yup","yeah"];
if (userResponsesArray.indexOf(userAnswer) !== -1) // This will check if the user answer exists in the list of acceptable responses. 
{
 // If the user answer is an acceptable response, come here.
}
```

Links: [Array.Indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: I like that `toLowerCase` addition. Personally, I'd dump the array into the if, instead of creating a variable for it, though. +1 for topping all of use here. Also, it'd be nice if you could explain how the code works, for those that don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (userAnswer==="yes" || userAnswer==="ya")
```